# how to express `there is a child node in current node` in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to parse the html file as :
    1)when there is child mode in td,please output  stage1
    2)when there is no child mode in td ,please output stage2

how to finish my code?

```
data='''
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span>  hallo
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  hallo
</td>
</tr>
</table> '''
import lxml.html
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(data)
set=root.xpath('//table//tr//td')
for cell in set:
    if(there is a child node in current node):
        print("stage1")
    else:
        print("stage2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `getchildren()` method:

```
for cell in set:
    print "stage1" if cell.getchildren() else "stage2"
```

prints:

```
stage1
stage2
```

Since the first `td` has `span` inside, the second `td` doesn't have any children.

UPD:

```
for cell in set:
    children = cell.getchildren()
    if not children:
        print "stage2"
    else:
        print "stage1"
        for child in children:
            print child.xpath('node()')[0].strip()
```

Comment: 1.how to use xpath `child::node()` to do 2.how can i get the name of the children node?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature sure, see he `UPD` section. Is this what you were looking for?